# Disabling monitor when is turned off/in standby in a multi-monitor setup

Tags: multi-monitor, kubuntu

I have a dual monitor setup. The problem is that 50% of the time I don't need my second monitor, and as such I will "turn it off" (i.e. press the power button ⏻) which results in the screen going in standby mode.

The problem is: my system still thinks that the monitor is displaying stuff and hence will try to open windows on that monitor, even modal dialogs triggered by applications display in the active monitor, which sometimes is really confusing if you open them by mistake with some shortcut and suddenly you can't do anything.

I would like my OS to detect the monitor and simply do not consider it. Basically when I press the power off button the setup of the monitor should go into single-monitor state (i.e. no windows will be opened on that monitor and any window open there should go in the opened monitor but in the background), and when I turn it on again it should change to dual-monitor state.

Is this possible at all? I believe some kind of signal arrives to the kernel so it ought to be possible to at least write a daemon that keeps track of which monitors are displaying and which not.

My system is:

- Kubuntu 18.04
- GPU: Nvidia 1080
- Dual monitors connected via DisplayPorts connected to the GPU

Comment: I'd like the opposite! When I turn off my DisplayPort monitor it moves everything around but I'd like it to stay put, as though the monitor is still there.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y Trust me... it's damn annoying. You "lose the mouse" very often. Modal dialogs are a pain in the ass because sometimes one might appear and you aren't even aware and it takes 10 seconds before realizing it, and after that you have to move it to the main monitor which either requires going to the task bar, right clicking moving and moving to monitor or you have to set up shortcuts to move windows between monitors (I have them mostly due to this...).

Comment: I'm considering writing some piece of software or patching something to achieve this, but I have 0 knowledge of kernel & stuff or how to detect such events from the displayports etc.